# How to display an image in Flash datagrid after selecting an image for uploading?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image, datagrid, upload

After browsing for the images, and selecting them. How can I display a preview of the image in the datagrid? I am able to display the file name, file size, but was unable to display the image. Below are the codes I have written, please note it is not a complete code but just enough to make it understandable. Thanks.

```
// variables used
var list:Array = new Array();
var listDP:Array = new Array();
var fileRefList:FileReferenceList;

//dgMain is my DataGrid instance
dgMain.addColumn("name");
dgMain.addColumn("size");

list = fileRefList.fileList; // List of files that user has selected

for(var i:Number = 0; i < list .length; i++) 
{
   list_dp.push({name:list[i].name, size:Math.round(list[i].size / 1000) + " kb"});
}

dgMain.dataProvider = new DataProvider(list_dp);
dgMain.spaceColumnsEqually();
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  Just load each of the images when you hear the `Event.SELECT` event on `FileReferenceList`.  Then create an itemRenderer for the datagrid that can display the returned ByteArray.  Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler()">


    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            // variables used
            var list:Array;
            var files:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var fileReferenceList:FileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();

            protected function creationCompleteHandler():void
            {
                fileReferenceList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
            }

            protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                load();
            }

            protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                var fileReference:FileReference = event.target as FileReference;
                var token:Object = {name:fileReference.name, size:Math.round(fileReference.size / 1000) + " kb", preview:fileReference.data};
                files.addItem(token);
            }

            public function load():void
            {
                list = fileReferenceList.fileList; // List of files that user has selected
                var i:int = 0;
                var n:int = list.length
                for(i; i < n; i++) 
                {
                    list[i].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                    list[i].load();
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Button label="browse" click="fileReferenceList.browse()"/>

    <mx:DataGrid id="dgMain"
        dataProvider="{files}"
        horizontalScrollPolicy="on"
        allowMultipleSelection="true" rowHeight="25">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="preview" headerText="preview">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Canvas verticalCenter="0" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                            <mx:Image source="{data.preview}" width="20" height="20"/>
                        </mx:Canvas>
                    </mx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="size" headerText="Size" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

If this solved the issue, mark it as correct :).

Best,
Lance

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for your reply. As I am quite new to Flash and do not have the software for Flex, is the above codes for Flex? Can I do the same for Flash as well? If so, how do I go about having the equivalent of itemRenderer in my Flash Datagrid. Currently, I have a DataGrid component already. Thanks!

Comment: hey, I've never used Flash so I'm not sure on the specifics of the datagrid in Flash.  But the code for FileReferenceList in the completeHandler and load methods should be fine.  Let me know if you've tried it.

Comment: Hi Lance, I managed to get Flex and tried your codes. However I hit an error on the line var token:Object = {name:fileRef.name, size:Math.round(fileRef.size / 1000) + " kb", preview:fileRef.data};

The error I had was "Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type flash.net:FileReference". I am currently using Flash Version 10.0.2.54.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem by updating my Flex SDK. Thanks. I'm unable to mark your answer as correct as I do not have enough reputation, am quite new to stackoverflow.

Comment: good to hear! how much reputation do you need to mark an answer as correct?

Comment: Its 15 reputation, i'm at 11.